# How to measure pulse_in in Python

Tags: python

I have a need to measure pulse in Python. I was using pycom .pulses_get.  But this is not working since I can't import pycom. Are there any alternative functions to pulses_get?

My code is given below:

```
import pyfirmata
from pyfirmata import util
import pycom
import time

# code for combining arduino with pycharm:

port = pyfirmata.Arduino('com4')
iterator = util.Iterator(port)
iterator.start()

trigpin = 12
echopin = 13
speedOfSound = 776.5 
start = 1
while start > 0:
    port.digital[trigpin].write(0)
    time.sleep(.002)
    port.digital[trigpin].write(1)
    time.sleep(1.5e-5)
    port.digital[trigpin].write(0)
    time.sleep(1e-5)
    port.digital[echopin].write(1)
    pingTime = pycom.pulses_get()
    pingTime = pingTime / 1000000
    pingTime = pingTime / 3600
    targetDistance1 = speedOfSound * pingTime
    targetDistance2 = targetDistance1 / 2
    targetDistance3 = targetDistance2 * 63360
    print(targetDistance3)
```

Comment: Are you looking for alternatives to ``pycom`` or do you actually want to fix being unable to import it? What error do you get?

Comment: I want alternatives

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761806/how-can-i-use-an-arduino-ultrasonic-sensor-connected-to-an-arduino-uno-to-measur